# Combining different properties of two different arrays of objects in one array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have one array of objects and two objects

array of objects something like  this

```
 [ { id: 1, name: 'Monthly Plan', cycle: 1, fees: 1000 },
      { id: 2, name: 'Yearly Plan', cycle: 12, fees: 10000 },
      { id: 3, name: 'Two Months Plan', cycle: 2, fees: 1500 },
      { id: 4, name: 'Three Months Plan', cycle: 3, fees: 2500 },
      { id: 5, name: 'Four Months Plan', cycle: 4, fees: 3000 }]
```

and now comes the objects actually I am making these objects by running a for loop something like this

```
if (newPlans) {
       newPlans.forEach(element => {
       let object = {};
       object.id = element.id;
       object.name = element.name,
       object.cycle = element.cycle,
       object.fees = element.fees
       console.log(object);
       console.log(Object.assign(billPlans.filter(bp => bp.id), object))
 });

  }
```

and I want to get result something like this

```
[ { id: 1, name: 'Monthly Plan', cycle: 1, fees: 1000 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Yearly Plan', cycle: 12, fees: 10000 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Two Months Plan', cycle: 2, fees: 1500 },
  { id: 4, name: 'Three Months Plan', cycle: 3, fees: 2500 },
  { id: 5, name: 'Four Months Plan', cycle: 4, fees: 3000 },
  { id: 6, name: 'Five Months Plan', cycle: 5, fees: 4000 } 
  { id: 7, name: 'Six Months Plan', cycle: 6, fees: 5000 } ]
```

but I am getting something like this

```
//console.log(object)
{ id: 6, name: 'Five Months Plan', cycle: 5, fees: 4000 }

 //console.log(object.assign)
[ { id: 1, name: 'Monthly Plan', cycle: 1, fees: 1000 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Yearly Plan', cycle: 12, fees: 10000 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Two Months Plan', cycle: 2, fees: 1500 },
  { id: 4, name: 'Three Months Plan', cycle: 3, fees: 2500 },
  { id: 5, name: 'Four Months Plan', cycle: 4, fees: 3000 },
  id: 6,
  name: 'Five Months Plan',
  cycle: 5,
  fees: 4000 ]

 //console.log(object)
{ id: 109, name: 'Six Months Plan', cycle: 6, fees: 5000 }

 //console.log(object.assign)
[ { id: 1, name: 'Monthly Plan', cycle: 1, fees: 1000 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Yearly Plan', cycle: 12, fees: 10000 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Two Months Plan', cycle: 2, fees: 1500 },
  { id: 4, name: 'Three Months Plan', cycle: 3, fees: 2500 },
  { id: 5, name: 'Four Months Plan', cycle: 4, fees: 3000 },
  id: 7,
  name: 'Six Months Plan',
  cycle: 6,
  fees: 5000 ]
```

As you can see the `Object.assign` is overriding the previously added object and `object` is  assigning not in correct way as you can see it is not assigned in the object way so how can I achieve this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not to assign, but push the object into the array.

If the `billPlans` is the above array with 5 elements, you need just to do

```
let object = {};
object.id = element.id;
object.name = element.name,
object.cycle = element.cycle,
object.fees = element.fees

billPlans.push(object);
```

Also I don't know why you are filtering the array, but the main concept is to push into the array, not use `Object.assign`.

`Object.assign` just copies the properties from the destinations into the source object.

Answer (score 0):

Expounding further to the previous answer given, try using a more functional approach that doesn't risk mutating data as a side effect. `.forEach()` will run a loop, executing a given function at each index, but will NOT preserve data as it was originally passed. Instead use, `.map()`, `.filter()`, or `.reduce()` depending in your end goal. Looking at your code and question as is, `.map()` works fine (though you can easily chain `.filter()`/`.reduce()` or even more `.map()` methods to the original `.map()`. `.forEach()` is not chain-able.

```
const ObjGenerator = (newPlans) =>  
    !newPlans ? null :
         newPlans
           .map(el => { ...el }
           .map(obj => {
             console.log(obj)
             return obj
           }
           .map(obj => {
            // rather than using the immutable `.push()` method, try 
            // the non-immutable alternative via `.concat()`
            // Also, dynamic invocation of Object.assign provided.

            return Object.assign.apply(billPlans.filter(bp => bp.id), [{}].concat(obj))
           }

ObjGenerator(newPlans)
```

Using the approach I describe also removes any duplicate entries that may get created.